# expection of random variable when the index also follows som

Tags: statistics

[image]

i don't have any clue to this question but because here the index also foloows a certain distribution please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clue:
$$\mathbb E(X_1+\cdots+X_N)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb E(X_1+\cdots+X_N\mid N=k)P(N=k)$$

The fact that $N$ is independent of the $X_i$'s allows the conclusion that:$$\mathbb E(X_1+\cdots+X_N\mid N=k)=\mathbb E(X_1+\cdots+X_k)$$

Comment: can't understand?

Comment: Do you know what the expression $\mathbb E(X_1+\cdots+X_N\mid N=k)$ stands for?

Comment: the conditional expectation given N=k..but how to proceed

Comment: Evidently $\mathbb E(X_1+\cdots+X_N\mid N=k)=\mathbb E(X_1+\cdots +X_k)=\mathbb EX_1+\cdots+\mathbb EX_k=k$. The second equality because of linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):

$$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\right]=E\left[E\left[\sum_{i=1}^NX_i|N\right]\right]=E\left[\sum_{i=1}^NE[X_i]\right]$$

Now if the $X_i$ have the same distribution:

$$\sum_{i=1}^NE[X_i]=NE[X_1]$$

Finally, we get, by linearity of expectation, $E[N]E[X_1]$.